# Ruby installation fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I tried to re-install Ruby using rvm . When I tried irb, this came up:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

please help

Comment: Can you explain what you did to try to install ruby?  What OS?  What version of ruby?

Comment: I used rvm on a ubuntu systme for ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Have you looked at `$ rvm notes`, as suggested [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/os/ubuntu/)? There is a comment about it. Also, if you installed with sudo (or are invoking irb with sudo), that could cause issues with where it installs and looks for files.

Comment: I reinstalled it without sudo and it still isn't working.

Comment: too few information you gave us.

Answer (score 2):

RVM allows installing different versions of rubygems:

```
rvm rubygems latest     # installs the version locked in RVM = latest-1.8
rvm rubygems latest-1.8 # installs the latest version 1.8.x known for rubygems
rvm rubygems 1.8.19     # installs the given version
```

Comment: this dosen't answer the question at all

Comment: for the little information you provide this is the only answer I could get for you, at least gist the log of ruby installation

Comment: All three of the above (adjusted for version per `ruby -v`) are giving me `ERROR: Rubygems version may only be set for an RVM MRI based Ruby, please select one and rerun.`

Comment: for what ruby do you get that problem? (`rvm current`)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
rvm info
```

to see if you are missing the zsh package.
if you do,install it and add this line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to `$HOME/.zshrc`